# Can someone explain this internet issue I had?

Tags: firefox, dns

I was on Cytube watching videos using Firefox, then I saw a Firefox update and said sure why not, updated the browser. After updating and opening Cytube again, I was met with one of those parked domain looking pages with the title of the website.

[image: https://u.teknik.io/6YlsP.png]

This is not the actual webpage, I didn't screenshot it, but it looked very close to this. This went on for about a minute until the real Cytube loaded, and that was that.
I was spooked, though, this never happened to me, so I did a full virus scan and nothing got picked up. I am still curious as to what could've caused this.

Comment: My gut feeling is that your update of Firefox has utterly nothing to do with this issue. Lots of different possibilities. Might even depend on what country you are in and whether you were using a VPN or not. Not to mention Cytube is basically a pirate site. So who knows what happened at that moment.

Comment: Asking to update firefox, or someother software, is a classic case of having your system compromised. It is likely that this `firefox update` was not what it says it was, and instead you have installed malware.

Comment: `cytu.be` looks like it runs through Cloudflare or a similar service. A guess would be that that service redirected you somewhere else temporarily for some reason.

Comment: I am not using a VPN. I upgraded from Firefox 98.0.1 to 98.0.2, it was asking to update for a couple days and I do virus scans regularly so I doubt the update was compromised. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @DaGeezerr everyone with a bit of knowledge about common [obfuscation techniques](https://www.socinvestigation.com/most-common-malware-obfuscation-techniques/) can reliably prevent your antivirus from detecting his malicious software. Your antivirus will protect you from "script kiddie" malware, nothing more.

Comment: @mashuptwice well my files aren't encrypted, my accounts aren't stolen, my performance is the same and nothing else is different. I don't have reason to believe my system is compromised because of this minor oddity.

Comment: @DaGeezerr: Are you certain you didn't mistype the URL? It’s common for companies to register URL’s that are typos of popular ones

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It is not your Firefox.

Just check what Google says

https://www.google.com/search?q=cytu.be

It is "for sale."

Additionally:

https://who.is/whois/cytu.be

There you can see it was changed about 24 hours ago:

> Information Updated: 2022-03-25 21:22:29

DNS takes some time until you get changes.

The update of your Firefox may have cleaned your DNS cache. If you know the old IP, set a host entry. Maybe the old webserver ist still hosting what you need.

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but one second your answer says the domain is “for sale” basing this on a Google search. I checked and I don’t see any indication from the Google search that the domain `cytu.be` is for sale. Then next you state that the Whois shows the record changed. So what is the actual answer here? Based on the original poster’s question and your WHOIS discovery it seems like the original poster somehow updated Firefox around the same time that a domain came up for renewal. Weird coincidence, but hey. _That_ is the answer now the “for sale” explanation.